# What changes should I apply to this code in order to run it faster?

Tags: python, performance, geocoding, shapefile

I wrote a python script for satellite image processing. Basically, what the code does is look over every window around every pixel from an image and compare it to a specific region of interest from the same image. The window that has the most similar information is stored and converted into a geospatial vector.

Allow me to further explain: I have monthly satellite images ranging from 2013 to 2020 of a specific location, summing up to 90 images (90 months). I also have a vector file (.shp) with 52 features, my regions of interest (ROI's). For each month, i.e., each image, I have to look over my ROI's, collect the digital value of all the pixels within the ROI, and calculate its average digital value. I do the same thing for all possible 3x3 pixels (window) from that image and compare their means. In the end, every ROI has a counterpart window, which has the smaller Euclidian Distance between their average digital values. The outputs are 90 vector files(.shp, each one corresponding to an image/month), with 52 windows by vector file, each kernel corresponding to a window that has the closest information to the ROI.

Not every pixel in an image is allowed to be part of the kernel, so I also have 90 masks that allow me to test if that window is electable.

The problem is that each monthly vector is taking about 8 hours to be generated. In total, it took me about 30 days to generate all the vectors, although I have a fairly good machine (w10, 64bit, intelCorei7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz, gtx8520m, 4GB ram ...). I understand that nested  `for` loops are not the best practice when coding, and also that python does not supports parallel computation very well (which I suspect would be the best approach since the windows are independent).

I tried different approaches, like the @jit, tried to use the GPU for the computation and also tried to use all 4 cores with the multiprocessing. The first two approaches didn't work, probably because my function is not suitable to be translated, as far as I understand. The last one ran without problems, but it took the double amount of time to finish it.

My question is: what changes should I apply to my code in order to make it faster, not only concerning "good writing", but also considering that I want to use all 4 cores and possibly my GPU for running it. I am not a computer scientist, therefore I am really struggling to find a solution.

Here is the code:

````
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
from rasterio.windows import Window
import rasterio
import numpy as np
from rasterstats import zonal_stats
from shapely.geometry import box
import os
import ntpath
import time



def path_leaf(path):
    head, tail = ntpath.split(path)
    return tail or ntpath.basename(head)


def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()

    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles


#The address of the folder containing the ROI's
SHP_address = 'F:\\nota_tecnica_2\\vetores\\amostras_interesse_final\\ROI_wgs84_9_final_dissolvido.shp'

#The address of the satellite images
a = getListOfFiles('C:\\dados_nota_tecnica\\MODIS\\MODIS_quality_mosaic_rec')

#The address of the masks (binary images where 0 is a electable pixel and 1 is a not electable pixel)
b = 'C:\\dados_nota_tecnica\\VIIRS\\final\\'

#The folder where I store my vectors at the end
c = 'F:\\nota_tecnica_2\\vetores\\amostras_controle\\'

#A variable defining which images from the "a" list should be analyzed 
_from = 0
_to = 90

#The function that will search for the windows 
def janela_movel(MODIS_list,local_viirs,saida):

    start = time.time()
    df_vazio = pd.DataFrame(
        {'mean_b1': [],
         'mean_b2': [],
         'mean_b4': [],
         'euc_dist': [],
         'left': [],
         'right': [],
         'bottom': [],
         'top': [],
         'id_alvo': []})

    for file in (range(_from,_to)): #len(MODIS_list)
        MODIS_address = MODIS_list[file]

        #Searches for a maks image that matches the name of the satellite image
        viirs_address = local_viirs+path_leaf(MODIS_address)

        #Open the matched mask image
        raster_viirs = rasterio.open(viirs_address)
        #Open the raster image
        raster_MODIS = rasterio.open(MODIS_address)



        #Caculates the average digital value in a ROI for 3 bands of the image (RED, GREEN and NEAR-INFRARED) (actually surface reflectance at NADIR);
        media_zonal_b1 = zonal_stats(SHP_address, MODIS_address,
                        stats="mean",
                        nodata=0,
                        all_touched=False,
                        categorical=False,
                        geojson_out=True,
                               band=1)
        media_zonal_b2 = zonal_stats(SHP_address, MODIS_address,
                        stats="mean",
                        nodata=0,
                        all_touched=False,
                        categorical=False,
                        geojson_out=True,
                               band=3)

        media_zonal_b4 = zonal_stats(SHP_address, MODIS_address,
                        stats="mean count",
                        nodata=0,
                        all_touched=False,
                        categorical=False,
                        geojson_out=True,
                               band=5)
        
        #Now the code will access the ROI. For each one it will extract not only the already computated mean value, but also the coordinates 
        #of the ROI and its ID (identificator) 
        for x in range(len(media_zonal_b1)):

            mean_band1_alvo = media_zonal_b1[x]['properties']['mean']
            mean_band2_alvo = media_zonal_b2[x]['properties']['mean']
            mean_band4_alvo = media_zonal_b4[x]['properties']['mean']
            id_alvo = x
            array_vazio = []
            #Here I set the size of the window/kernel
            
            i = 3
            j = 3
            #Now it will access the satellite image and move this 3x3 window through all pixels
            for i_r in range(raster_viirs.height):
                for j_r in range(raster_viirs.width):
                   row_start = i_r
                   row_stop = i_r + i
                   col_start = j_r
                   col_stop = j_r + j
                   Win = Window.from_slices(slice(row_start, row_stop), slice(col_start, col_stop))
                   croped = raster_viirs.read(window=Win)
                    
                    #This is some code to prevent NAN values and not electable pixels
                   if (-999.0 not in croped) and (1 not in croped) and (np.isnan(croped).any() != True):

                        bounds = raster_viirs.window_bounds(Win) 
                        croped2 = raster_MODIS.read(window=Win) #aplicando a janela extraída ao dado e reflectancia

                        
                        if ((np.isnan(croped2).any()) != True) and (croped2.size != 0):
                            mean_band1 = np.mean(croped2[0])
                            mean_band2 = np.mean(croped2[2])
                            mean_band4 = np.mean(croped2[4])
                            
                            if (mean_band1_alvo or mean_band2_alvo or mean_band4_alvo) is None:
                                mean_band1_alvo = -999
                                mean_band2_alvo = -999
                                mean_band4_alvo = -999
                                dist = -999
                            #Calculates the euclidian distance between the bands of the pixels within the window and the ROI
                            else:
                                dist = (((mean_band1 - mean_band1_alvo) ** 2) + ((mean_band2 - mean_band2_alvo) ** 2) + (
                                            (mean_band4 - mean_band4_alvo) ** 2)) ** 0.5

                                # Creates a dataframe with all the electable kernels
                                array_dados = [dist,mean_band1,mean_band2,mean_band4,bounds[0],bounds[1],bounds[2],bounds[3]]

                                #aggreagte the kernels in a single array
                                array_vazio = array_vazio+array_dados


            #Transforms in a 2d array and order it to find the most alike kernel (smallest euclidian distance)
            array_dados_2d = np.reshape(array_vazio, (-1,8))
            array_dados_2d = array_dados_2d[np.argsort(array_dados_2d[:, 0])]

            #Number of windows per ROI
            numero_de_amostras = 1
            array_dados_filtered = array_dados_2d[0:numero_de_amostras, ]
            #Accumulates the windows of all the ROI in a single vector (.shp file)
            df_dados = pd.DataFrame(
             {'euc_dist': array_dados_filtered[:, 0],
              'mean_b1': array_dados_filtered[:, 1],
              'mean_b2': array_dados_filtered[:, 2],
              'mean_b4': array_dados_filtered[:, 3],
              'left': array_dados_filtered[:, 4],
              'bottom': array_dados_filtered[:, 5],
              'right': array_dados_filtered[:, 6],
              'top': array_dados_filtered[:, 7],
              'id_alvo': id_alvo})
            df_vazio = df_vazio.append(df_dados, ignore_index = True)

        #Some geocoding for the output vector file. 
        bbox = df_vazio.apply(lambda row: box(row.left, row.bottom, row.right, row.top), axis=1)
        geo_dataframe = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df_vazio, geometry=bbox)
        geo_dataframe.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
        local = saida
        geo_dataframe.to_file(driver = 'ESRI Shapefile', filename= (local+path_leaf(MODIS_address)+'.shp'))

        df_vazio = pd.DataFrame(
            {'mean_b1': [],
             'mean_b2': [],
             'mean_b4': [],
             'euc_dist': [],
             'left': [],
             'right': [],
             'bottom': [],
             'top': [],
             'id_alvo': []})
    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

#finally appling the function
janela_movel(a,b,c)```
````

Comment: Have used a profiler or the timeit module to see which parts of your code are the slowest? I see you've used time.time(), but I think getting a bit more granular could help to hone in on the largest time sinks.

Comment: Also probably not going to make a drastic difference, but specifying your dataframe dtypes as input parameters should help so pandas doesn't have to guess which slows things down quite a bit. You may also be able to use less precision for some fields and substitute numeric dtypes for strings (object dtype).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is probably the very high amount of call to `raster_MODIS.read` which probably perform a **slow I/O operation**. Moreover, each cell is actually read 9 times (in average) due to the window size.

To solve that, you can **read the whole raster into memory** in a 2D numpy array and work directly on it. If the raster is too big, it can be *split in line bands* or even 2D tiles (although this is a bit complex).

Then, if this is not enough, you can then put the numpy computational part (the 2 nested inner loops) in a function and speed it up with **numba @njit** (note that it will be better/faster if `array_vazio` is a 2D numpy array allocated directly with the good size, or even with an overestimated size, as numba does not like Python lists).

Finally, if this is still not enough, you can try to use the **multiprocessing** module to compute each raster in parallel (in a separate process and merge process data at the end).

The resulting code should be *several order of magnitude faster*.